# Differences between adfc-config.xml and faces-config.xml?

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, faces-config, adfc-config

Both files seem very similar, subsequently I'm struggling to understand their purposes.

I have seen faces-config referred to as a plain JSF controller, while adfc-config is an extended ADF controller.

Some clarification would be good, as right now I can't see why you would have both in an ADF application if that is the case, so I must be missing something.

Answer (score 2):

adfc-config is different from faces-config

Faces Config is the controller of your application, it's what make JSF based frameworks work effectively, and it's where you will need to define your own customization like view handlers, converters, validators, etc...

adfc-config is just the main application unbounded Task Flow, which make it a little easier for developers to define their pages and main navigation root inside of it instead of doing it the JSF way and define them in faces config, it also provide additional functionality like defining managed beans which will have much more scopes than the original JSF given the ADF Framework additions, but still at the end it's just an Unbounded Task Flow. Here is the [documentation reference about adfc-config.xml](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/adf/ADFFD/appendixa.htm#BABHFIFA)

Answer (score 0):

adfc-config is used by the ADF Faces framework, when task flows are in the picture.

More information at: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/b31974/taskflows.htm

Yes, you are right when you say that the functionality looks similar. Things like pageFlowScope / backingBeanScope / task flows / etc. are extensions to the standard JSF framework and require a custom configuration file.

So, if you create a project based on the Fusion WebApplication template, then you will see a default adfc-config.xml file entry.

Hope that helps.